# Problem with ajax calling from facebook app

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following code in order to make an ajax call to my server.
The code makes the call to the server and in return, it gets a list of all the friends that use the same app.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
        uid = response.session.uid;
        access_token = response.session.access_token;
        $.getJSON(serverLink+"ajax.php?action=getFriendsApp", {token:access_token}
         ,function(data){
         var temp = data;
         if(true){
                var container = $('#friends_part_main');
                var fp = $('#friends_part');
                fp.show();
                var friends = data;
                for(var i in friends){
                    container.append('<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='+friends[i]+'">\n\
                    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+friends[i]+'/picture" alt="friend" />\n\
                    </a>');     
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

If I run this code directly from the browser (www.mydomain.com/app) it works.
But when I run it from the canvas page (app.facebook.com) I get the foloowing error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.mydomain.com/src/ajax.php?action=getFriendsApp&token=AAAC0kxh1WAcBAHo3s0QaVy34mgdnCNGvrDZCvIQsZCBHZC8ovR9IuYEFlUKRqK0GgJosWAD6Embg8QrN07vivE6mOuAZAtxUD7WpySDL3wZDZD.
>   Origin https://www.mydomain.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Can you figure out why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need JSONP or to allow ajax requests on your domain. You can force it with

```
header("Allow-Access-Control-Origin:*");
```

Comment: I tried to add that in the beginning of my php file but it still doesn't work. Do you anymore suggestions?

Comment: Can I have two header statements?

Comment: @SharonHaimPour: sure you can

Comment: @SharonHaimPour: so use JSONP

Comment: Works now. Had to change the serverLink variable to use SSL.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the domain in the URL of my ajax page "ajax.php" and the URL of the ajax-calling-page "index.php" weren't exactly the same. "www" missed... 
You have to check that your two scripts domains (the calling script and the responding script) are exacty the same ! Check the "http" vs "https", check the "https://my-domain.com" vs "https://www.my-domain.com" etc.
Hope it helps.
xxx

Comment: although genesis' answer is without a doubt correct, I think this indeed is a more common mistake with starting facebook app developers. because a facebook app resides in an iframe, there is no actual cross-domain ajax traffic. But: facebook may load your page with http:// or http:// since you can provide both protocols in the app settings page on the facebook developers website.
So a quick tip for PHP people : use `isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])` to determine what ajax-url to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your XMLHttpRequest is not allowed by access control allow origin because facebook load your application via secure https, but you could access only http. You can't load from other sundomain, protocol or port.
Try JSONP with callback function. You can load Javascript code from any place, if your response contain not only data, but callback function, you could access any data from any place of your server (site).